# Residue formula for fraction

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose the function $f(z)=\dfrac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=a$. (So $q(z)$ has a zero of order $2$ at $z=a$.) Then the residue at $z=a$ of $f(z)$ is $$\dfrac{d}{dz}(z-a)^2\dfrac{p(z)}{q(z)}$$

Why is this equal to $$\dfrac{p'(a)}{q''(a)/2}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $q(z) = \frac12 q''(a)(z-a)^2 + (z-a)^3\tilde{q}(z)$ where $\tilde{q}$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $a$. Then

$$(z-a)^2\frac{p(z)}{q(z)} = \frac{p(z)}{q''(a)/2 + (z-a)\tilde{q}(z)}.$$

Differentiating that yields

$$\frac{d}{dz}\bigl\lvert_{z=a}(z-a)^2\frac{p(z)}{q(z)} = \frac{p'(z)}{q''(a)/2} - \frac{p(a)\tilde{q}(a)}{(q''(a)/2)^2},$$

which does not agree with your formula.